# How do I set the site-package directory for pycharm and spyder?

Tags: pycharm, spyder

I know that I can set the python interpreter by locating the python.exe or conda.exe.

My question is how do I set the site-package directory for pycharm and spyder ? So that when I install a new package in `cmd` via `pip`, I can be sure that this particular library/package is available in my pycharm and spyder.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the same interpreter in PyCharm and Spyder?

Comment: Yes i use same interpreter

Comment: Then, if you install a package on this interpreter, it should be available in both

Comment: What if they are different ? How do i go about that ?

Comment: Then it is better to run installation twice: on the interpreter used in PyCharm and the one used in Spyder